# Incorporating django-tables2 into Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-cms, django-tables2

How can I use django-tables2 output in django-cms templates? Since django-cms using plugins for page elements, should I write a custom plugin for it to work with the tables I generated with django-tables 2? I have other elements such as django-filter forms, can they be incorporated into Django-cms as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a django CMS plugin [1] which uses your django-tables2 models.

[1] http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html

Comment: Thanks @ojii,

But I am having problems figuring out how to write it as a custom plugin. This is the first time I'm doing it. Currently I am using CBV method of calling Django-tables2 and I am not sure if that method can be used in the custom plugin. 

How would you imaging doing it? I have a listview and a detailview page that both require the table plugin. I managed to start a form for the model and table_class for the plugin but I'm not sure how to patch it to the Django-tables2 code. Thank you for your input!